# pdf.js running on node raises errors because HTMLElement and Image are NOT DEFINED

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, canvas, pdf.js

I am developing a **node** function which reads a pdf file and generates an image out of the first page.

To accomplish this I use **pdf.js** library, which I have installed with the command `npm install pdfjs-dist`. My code is basically a copy of the [node example](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/node/pdf2png/pdf2png.js) provided with **pdf.js**.

When I execute the code that implement my logic, I encounter first the error ***HTMLElement is not defined***.

I fix this error changing the **pdf.js** code from the original

```
if (imgData instanceof HTMLElement || !imgData.data)
```

to the new

```
if ((typeof HTMLElement !== 'undefined' && imgData instanceof HTMLElement) || !imgData.data)
```

Then, fixed the first problem, I step into the second error ***Image is not defined***.

I fix this error adding at the beginning of **pdf.js** source file the following lines

```
var Canvas = require("canvas");
global.Image = Canvas.Image;
```

Once I have done these 2 fixes, everything works.

I am pretty sure though that this is not the way the library **pdf.js** is intended to be used, so I am wondering what I am missing.

Comment: The node example link you shared says "not found" can u pls check?

Comment: Are you using an old version by any chance ? I see a related issue in their repo, that was fixed. https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/8489

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48692469/edit) the question to include a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

Althrouth `pdf.js` is primarily designed for browser environment, it can be used in node environment, there are compatible code in the pdf.js codebase. However, at times, the examples and documentation may not function as expected.

I did some work in https://github.com/Priestch/pdfjs-dist-image-demo to make the node image example work, it use pdfjs-dist 3.x version, because the latest 4.x use esm module default, which I think may not compatible with the `canvas`  package, it use a cjs module.

Answer (score -3):

Tinkering directly with a library's source code is like using a sledgehammer for surgery—effective, perhaps, but hardly elegant or sustainable. Your approach, while creative, veers off the path of best practices. `pdf.js` is primarily designed for browser environments; hence, the errors you've encountered in Node.js are expected but not insurmountable.

Firstly, your manual adjustments are makeshift fixes that bind you to a specific `pdf.js` version, complicating updates and maintenance. The real solution lies in understanding the pdf.js environment and adapting your Node.js environment to mimic that, not rewriting the library.

For the `HTMLElement is not defined` issue, your conditional fix is a classic case of treating symptoms rather than the disease. `pdf.js` seeks a browser-like environment. Your Node.js setup should provide necessary shims or polyfills for browser-specific objects like `HTMLElement` and `Image` without altering `pdf.js` itself.

Regarding the `Image is not defined` error, preemptively requiring `canvas` and globally assigning `Canvas.Image` to `Image` might seem clever, but it's a hack that could lead to future headaches. A more sophisticated approach would leverage existing Node.js packages designed to polyfill these APIs or use conditional logic within your application to provide these functionalities only when `pdf.js` runs in Node.js.

Comment: This is more opinion and philosophy than answer. "pdf.js" does support Node and does not require DOM for most of its features, see https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#faq-support and https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/node/getinfo.mjs